# Automatically filling a field when a form is opened

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that allows people to enter deliveries. Each delivery has an ID, and the Autonumber feature would work except that I need to accommodate my organization's previous numbering scheme for deliveries so I can't simply Autonumber 1, 2, 3 etc.

What I need is for the ID field to be the string "DD" followed by the date m/d/y and then a number representing which delivery on that date.

So the first delivery today would be DD0427151 then the next would be DD0427152 and the first one tomorrow would be DD0428151 and so on.

I am trying to write VBA code so that during the event, when the form is opened, it sets the ID area of the form equal to what I want. Here is the code I am using, but failing with:

```
Private sub Form_Open(cancel as Integer) 
ID.Value="DD" & Date()
end sub
```

I know this won't do exactly what I want, but if I can get this to work then I can use if then statements to deal with the rest of it I think.

I get an error saying "You can't assign a value to this object"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Open is way too soon to assign anything. The best method to use would be either Load or Current. Saying that, Current would be more appropriate as Load is triggered only once when the form is opened. Current is triggered every time it travels to a record.

Considering your particular scenario, this might be a bit tricky and not to mention really unconventional. The [fundamental principle of DB design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IA4ZUEEPrQU) suggests that the **Data should be atomic**, considering your situation you are storing several components in one single field. This does not only breaks the design principle but also ignores the concept of indexing, and optimizing.

All that being said, here is what your code might need to be.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim tmpID as String, tmpCtr As Long
    tmpCtr = 1
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.yourControlName = "DD" & Format(Date(), "mmddyy") & tmpCtr
        While DCount("*", "yourTableName", "fieldName = '" & Me.yourControlName & "'") <> 0 
            tmpCtr = tmpCtr + 1
            Me.yourControlName = "DD" & Format(Date(), "mmddyy") & tmpCtr
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

This is one part of the solution, if the system is used by multiple users. The code also needs to be implemented in the BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: Thanks @PaulFrancis but it isn't working still for two reasons. The & Format(Date, "MMDDYY") & is not working so the field opens as just DD1. Then the DCount function gives me run-time error '3075' missing operator in query expression.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I am not sure why you would have problem uising Format function. Syntax error suggest the ID field is not really a Text field. Could you try and explain a little bit more?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed brackets around my fieldname. Thanks

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. Happy to help :)

Comment: The only problem I am having is that Format(Date(), "mmddyy") doesn't print out anything. I am getting DD1, then DD2 and so on, but no date. I tried a few different things but no luck. Take a look at my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924075/inserting-date-into-string-vba-access

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post more of your code and I might modify this answer a little if you do.

There are a number of ways to deal with this, but here's one easy possibility.

Suppose you created a textbox on your form called "IdBox" and your form is called "MyUserForm" then you could do this:

```
Dim MyForm As MyUserForm
Set MyForm = New MyUserForm
MyForm.IdBox.Text = "DD" & Date()
MyForm.Show
```

That should get you the result you are looking for.

A little better might be to create a property in your form:

```
Private pID As String
Public Property Let ID(value As String)
    pID = value
End Property
Public Property Get ID() As String
    ID = pID
End Property
```

And then setting the value of that property after you create your from:

```
Dim MyForm As MyUserForm
Set MyForm = New MyUserForm
MyForm.ID = "DD" & Date()
MyForm.Show
```

But you would also need to add the activate event handler to your form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.IdBox.Text = Me.ID
End Sub
```

And that should do it.

There is also a .Tag property that you could use, but I think that's roughly equivalent to using a public or global variable.  Roughly anyway.  You could look up the details on that elsewhere.