# Inserting date into string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In VBA, I am setting a field in a form equal to a string like so:

```
tmpNum=1
me.field="DD" & Format(DATE, "mmddyy") & tmpNum
```

For today I would want me.field to be DD0428151 but instead the whole Format(DATE, "mmddyy") statement seemingly does nothing and I get DD1 in the form.

Does anyone understand why the date isn't appearing in my string and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange things like this can happen if you have a field named `Date` in your table and/or a control named `Date` on your form. They will (at least sometimes) take precedence over the built-in `Date` function, and if they contain `Null` then the results can be similar to what you describe.

If possible, change the name of the field from `Date` to something more descriptive (or at least different). If you cannot change the name of the field then consider changing the Record Source of the form to something like

```sql
SELECT Table1.Foo, Table1.Date AS TheDate, ... FROM Table1
```

and then have your form use `TheDate` when it needs to manipulate the field or control.

Comment: Good call. I have another field named Date, and it is null so that is probably why this is happening. Thank you Gord